# Перевод строки в консольном приложении (C#)

Tags: c#, консоль, перенос

Насколько я знаю, для перевода строки в Windows используется сочетание управляющих символов \r\n. Но при разработке консольного приложения для этой цели можно обойтись только символом \n. Так, если в программе

```
using System;

namespace Test
{

 class Program
 {
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Имя: Иван\r\nФамилия: Иванов");
    }
 }
}
```

\r\n заменить на \n, то вывод от этого не изменится. При этом, например, в элементе управления TextBox, значение свойства Multiline которого равно True, приложения Windows Forms написать \n для перевода строки недостаточно, нужно обязательно писать \r\n. Например, если написать такой код:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
namespace TextBoxControls
{
 public partial class TextBoxControls : Form
 {
    public TextBoxControls()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBoxOutput.Text = "Имя: Иван\nФамилия: Иванов";
    }
  }
}
```

, то при нажатии на кнопку buttonOK в поле textBoxOutput никакого переноса не будет. Почему такая разница?

Comment: Чтобы не заморачиваться, есть такая вещь, как `Environment.NewLine`, которая работает и в винде, и в линуксе.

Comment: Пока читал ответил Артем

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\r\n` - стандарт переноса строки в Windows, он со времен MS-DOS не менялся, имеет аббревиатуру **CRLF** (Carriage Return Line Feed).

`\n` - стандарт переноса строки в UNIX (Linux, BSD, и т.д.), имеет аббревиатуру **LF**.

Почему консоль реагирует одинаково на оба варианта - вопрос к разработчикам консоли в Microsoft, но по стандарту гарантированно в Windows должен работать только стандарт **CRLF**.

Так как C# - это кроссплатформенный язык, и писать код на нем можно как под Windows, так и под Linux, чтобы решить проблему совместимости кода с обоими стандартами, была придумана переменная окружения `Environment.NewLine`. И в каком бы окружении вы бы не запустили код, с использованием этой переменной он будет работать.

Попробуйте

```cs
"Имя: Иван" + Environment.NewLine + "Фамилия: Иванов"
```

Подробнее про перенос строки можно почитать в [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8)

Answer (score 0):

Помнится в старых текстовых редакторах CRLF (\r\n) создавал новый абзац (с соответствующим форматированием), а LF (\n) создавал "мягкий" перенос строки без создания нового абзаца. Многострочные абзацы так и создавались. По аналогии сейчас в html `<br>` — для переноса строк и `<p>` — для создания абзацев.