# C# некорректно сравниваются строки методом .Contains

Tags: c#, строки

Пытаюсь сравнить две строки полученные из текстового файла на предмет того, содержит ли одна строка другую. Выдает всегда false. При этом если те же самые строки прописываю напрямую в коде, то выдает true. Сами строки в консоль выдаёт идентичные.
Вывод в консоль соответственно:

дрова для камина

дрова

True

дрова для камина

дрова

False

```
            string contents = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Bots\input.txt");
            string[] words = contents.Split('\n');
                        
            string oneTest = "дрова для камина";
            string twoTest = "дрова";
            

            string one = words[1];
            string two = words[0];
            
            bool b = oneTest.Contains(twoTest);
            bool d = oneTest.Contains(two);

            Console.WriteLine(oneTest);
            Console.WriteLine(twoTest);
            Console.WriteLine(b);
            Console.WriteLine(oneTest);
            Console.WriteLine(two);
            Console.WriteLine(d);
```

В файле input соответственно лежат эти же самые две строки.

Comment: Скопировал ваш пример, он не компилируется, воспроизвести не могу вашу проблему

Comment: [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Я отредактировал код, теперь должен компилироваться. Но нужно создать файл input с нужными данными

Comment: то есть по прежнему, даже если код скопировать, то воспроизвести вашу проблему не получится. А раз не воспроизводится, то и понять, что у вас происходит не выйдет, можно только гадать.

Comment: `.Split(Environment.NewLine)`. Наверняка разделителем строк являются два символа: `\r\n`.

Comment: Можно ещё обрезать лишнее попробовать `bool d = oneTest.Contains(two.Trim());`, вдруг там пробел в конце строки закрался

Comment: Отладка кода для таких случаев есть. Символ `\r` невидимый. А проблема вызвана невнимательностью.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Enviroment.NewLine помогло. Я знаю, что где-то упустил что-то. Не совсем невнимательность, я даже не знал про \r. Так что скорее проблема вызвана недостатком знаний, а нагуглить подобную проблему не удалось (так как было непонятно даже куда копать, про пробелы я первым делом подумал и проверил)

Comment: @Alex https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1161382/373567